# Creating a Pandas DataFrame from Uneven List of Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, key-value

I am trying to get a dictionary into a formatted DataFrame.

I am getting the data through an API call from: https://www.cryptonator.com/api

```
r = requests.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd')
x = r.json()
```

The data returned is in the format:

```
{"ticker":{"base":"BTC","target":"USD","price":"443.7807865468","volume":"31720.1493969300","change":"0.3766203596"},
"timestamp":1399490941,
"success":true,
"error":""
}
```

I am only interested in some of  the data in the dictionary "ticker" and the key value pair, "timestamp".

My issue is that since "ticker" is a dictionary within a dictionary whereas "timestamp" is simply a key value pair, I cannot seem to import them into this specific Pandas DataFrame:

```
  base           price   timestamp            volume
0  BTC  443.7807865468  1399490941  31720.1493969300
```

I've tried several methods that don't exactly give me what I'm looking for including:

```
pd.DataFrame(x).T 
                 base       change          price      target          volume
ticker            BTC  -8.71469546  1532.83742332         USD  22275.83826859
timestamp  1493925662   1493925662     1493925662  1493925662      1493925662
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out the pieces you need

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'ticker': x['ticker'],
        'timestamp': x['timestamp']
    }).T

                 base        change           price      target            volume
ticker            BTC  0.3766203596  443.7807865468         USD  31720.1493969300
timestamp  1399490941    1399490941      1399490941  1399490941        1399490941
```

***Old Answer***

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(x)

  error success ticker.base ticker.change    ticker.price ticker.target     ticker.volume   timestamp
0          True         BTC  0.3766203596  443.7807865468           USD  31720.1493969300  1399490941
```